# SQL query for multiple groups combining each group as an AND statement and within each group as an OR statement

Tags: mysql

I have a complex navigation that sorts a gallery of content.  The navigation corresponds to categories and the gallery needs to display different combinations of content based on what categories are selected in the navigation.  The navigation is structured like so:

```
GROUP 1
category 1
category 2
category 3

GROUP 2
category 4
category 5
category 6

GROUP 3
category 7
category 8
category 9
```

I need to write a MySQL query that treats all the items WITHIN each group as an OR statement.  So a selection of Category 1 and Category 2, should return all the items that are tagged with both Category 1 and Category 2.

And, the items BETWEEN each group need to be treated as an AND statement.  So, a selection of Category 1 and Category 4 would only return the items that are included in both Category 1 and Category 4.

I can accomplish both of those queries in their simple form but I can't seem to pull it off when I need to include multiple groups with multiple categories within each group.

In english, the final query needs to be able to do something like this:

```
"category 1" OR "category 2" OR "category 3" 
AND
"category 4" OR "category 5"
AND
"category 6" OR "category 7"
```

I've struggled with many versions of many queries for this and I currently don't have a working answer.  For reference, if it's worth it, here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT ct.entry_id,
    ct.entry_date AS date,
    ct.title AS title,
    cp.cat_id AS category_id
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS cd ON ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts AS cp ON ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id
WHERE ct.channel_id = '2'                        
AND ct.site_id = '1'

AND cp.cat_id IN (119)
AND cp.cat_id IN (121)

GROUP BY ct.entry_id 
ORDER BY ct.entry_date DESC
```

The cat_id lines in the where cause seems to be what needs to be sorted out.  I've also tried to use HAVING, which I got working in a broad sense, but I don't really understand it so as I try to modify it for more specific use (if it's even the right thing to be using) I'm not getting any useful results.  The variables in the query below are being dynamically constructed based on which categories are checked:

```
AND ct.entry_id IN (SELECT entry_id
                FROM exp_category_posts 
                WHERE cat_id IN (".$category_ids.") 
                GROUP BY entry_id
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id) = " . 
                count($category_array) . ")
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Thanks to Gordon's answer I now have a working query.  While some parts of the query are constructed dynamically (such as which category IDs are selected) here is a static version of the query for reference:

```
SELECT ct.entry_id,
   ct.entry_date AS date,
   ct.title AS title,
   cp.cat_id AS category_id
FROM exp_channel_titles AS ct
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS cd ON ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts AS cp ON ct.entry_id = cp.entry_id
WHERE ct.channel_id = '2'                        
AND ct.site_id = '1'
GROUP BY ct.entry_id 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN cp.cat_id IN (119,122) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
       MAX(CASE WHEN cp.cat_id IN (129,127) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
       MAX(CASE WHEN cp.cat_id IN (140) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
ORDER BY ct.entry_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you seem to have a table category_posts with multiple rows per entry_id.  You want the categories on the various rows of an entry_id to meet your conditions.

This requires a having clause:

```
select cp.entry_id
from category_posts cp left outer join
     group1 g1
     on cp.cat_id = g1.cat_id left outer join
     group2 g2
     on cp.cat_id = g2.cat_id left outer join
     group3 g3
     on cp.cat_id = g3.cat_id
group by cp.entry_id
having max(case when g1.cat_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when g2.cat_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when g3.cat_id is not null then 1 else 0 end)
```

That is, there is at least one representative category from each group.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. HAVING and CASE were new to me. The final query required that I use the IN clause but you're example really helped me go down the right path.  The final having query included: HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN cp.cat_id IN (119,122) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND ...  Cheers!